# Create a breadcrumb that shrinks with window but obscures content to the left

Tags: jquery, css

I need to make a breadcrumb nav that could be quite long, that shrinks with the window for small screens but the links inside it disappear to the left ie the most recently visited pages are always the ones in view, percentage width in CSS not working so was thinking JQuery.

Comment: What about `float: right`, `overflow: hidden` + some method of sizing it properly?

Comment: the breadcrumb needs to always sit to the left so thanks anyway but maybe I should have made that clearer and it may be only one link on some pages and it would need to be left aligned.

Comment: resizing it properly is basically the problem I tried float: left with overflow: hidden which kind of works but the most recent links disappear where I want the reverse to happen and the most recent links stay in view while the menu disappears on the left

Comment: The structure of my suggestion would be `wrapper` > `breadcrumb (float:right)` where `wrapper` is still left aligned and you use css magic, or possibly some simple javascript to size the breadcrumb so that new content adds to the width, which is then pushed off the left side.  That's just a rough idea, which may or may not take some more work to actually implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a combination of `direction: rtl;` and `overflow: hidden;`. For example, try this example code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adamschwartz/5VBB7/)).

**HTML**

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
  <a href="#">Home</a> &gt;
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Page</a> &gt; 
  <a href="#">Parent</a> &gt; 
  Current Page
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#breadcrumb {
  overflow: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  white-space: nowrap; /* keeps everything on one line */
  width: 50%; /* change this to whatever you want (for example, 300px) */
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, trouble is that if you minimise the page the links stay obscured and dont reappear. This is why I thought JQuery might be the way to go

Comment: Sorry minimise and then maximise again

Comment: What would you like the behavior to be instead?

Comment: More or less exactly as it works in FFox, where if you minimise the page the bcrumb moves to the left to be hidden, then when you maximise the browser again it flows back to the right re-revealing the bcrumb again. Thanks for responding, helped a lot in the end.